# How to prevent copy/paste in excel only for some columns or cells

Tags: vba, excel, apache-poi

Is there a way prevent copy/paste **for some columns** in Excel?.

Comment: You could prevent selection of locked cells. and lock these columns.

Comment: It is not enough, anyway it is possible to do copy/paste

Comment: To my knowledge the protection mecanism is the only way to prevent the user from doing that reliably. If that is not  enough for you, then i think it is impossible to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential workaround although it may not be satisfactory; you can make a range essentially unselectable therefore no copying or pasting would work as you can't actually select the data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LockedRange As Range: Set LockedRange = Me.Range(Columns(1), Columns(3))
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, LockedRange) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("D1").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but if I insert a column before the non-selectable column, then the initial column is selectable. I think the range of columns should be relative to finding a certain name in the header or something that identifies it.